# Can't export View Entries in a list to Excel

Tags: 2013, 2010, list, export

I have created a Project Tracker list with a custom column called "Status Updates." There will be many entries in this column as a project progresses. When you view the Project Tracker, you see a link in that column that says "View Entries" which shows all the entries when clicked. This works perfectly in the display, but this column is not included when I export the list to Excel. Is there any way to include the entries in this column when exporting?